# Python round a value to 3 decimal places

Tags: python

For some reasons the code below doesn't round the value to 3 decimal places but only 1. Any ideas?

```
for y in range(len(candidates_list)):
    analysis.write(f"\n{candidates_list[y]}: {round(percentages_list[y],3)}% ({candidates_votes[y]})")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):` use `for item in list:`

Comment: Are you trying to get `.300` instead of `.3`?

Comment: I am trying to get 20.000%

Comment: Following up on @Barmar's advice on iterating over a list, if you truly need the index, you can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 2):

Due you are using f-strings (and thats very cool instead of old `.format` style ), this is not a rounding representation of the number because the previous answer gives you the right way to do it, this is a truncated representation of the number on the f strings, but this answer may help to others.

Instead of printing

`f'{round(percentages_list[y],3)}'`

you can do:

`f'{percentages_list[y]:.3f}'`

Comment: Thank you, Luis!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `round()` function, use the appropriate formatting operations. This will including trailing zero digits after the decimal.

And use `zip()` to iterate through multiple lists in parallel, rather than list indexing.

```
for candidate, percentage, vote in zip(candidates_list, percentages_list, candidates_votes):
    analysis.write(f"\n{candidate}: {percentage:.3f}% ({vote}")
```

Comment: I am receiving this error:
    analysis.write(f"\n{candidate}: {percentage:%.3f}% ({vote})")
ValueError: Invalid format specifier

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have `%` in the format specifier

Comment: Thank you, Bramar!